# Overfitted model performs better in test set

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, deep-learning

I have asked this question [here](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/8867/overfitted-model-performs-better-in-test-set), but it seems people are not active there.

There are two models for the same task:

**model_1:** 98% accuracy on training set, 54% accuracy on test set.
**model_2:** 48% accuracy on training set, 47% accuracy on test set.

From the statistics above we can say that **model_1** overfits training set.
**Q1:** Can we say that **model_2** underfits?
**Q2:** Why **model_1** is bad choice if it performs better than **model_2** on test set?

Comment: AI Stack Exchange it not the appropriate place for such questions (and neither is SO); you should try [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) and/or [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) (I would kindly suggest the former)...

Answer (score 3):

First of all some preliminary points:

it would be useful to know if the task is a binary one. In that case you are obtaining a performance that is very close to the random choice. So basically your model are not learning from the training set.

Another useful information would be to know if the training set for the two model is the same (same splitting test/training). Because the difference of 7% between the two models could be just random noise due to the sample splitting.

Finally, to state the model_2 is better than model_1 you need a deeper analysis. it's highly probable that there is no statistical significance in the difference between the two models.

The fact that the model is over-fitting tells you that it is not generalizing well on the test-set. With a better choice of your design you can improve the performance and make the system more robust to unseen samples. The reason to not to use an overfitting system is that the accuracy of 54% is achieved on that specific test/validation set and could vary greatly on new unseen values due to the lack of generalizability and robustness of the model.

Answer (score 0):

**Q1** Yes, **model_2** underfits.

**Q2** Because, **model_2** instead of generalisation just remember answers. So performance on the test set will get worse the bigger the difference between train and test set.

Answer (score 0):

Citing [Ian Goodfellow's book, Chapter 5.2](http://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/ml.html):

> We must remember that while simpler functions are more likely to
>   generalize(to have a small gap between training and test error), we
>   must still choose a suﬃciently complex hypothesis to achieve low
>   training error.